# Upload file using Delphi CGI

Tags: delphi, cgi

Could anyone please give a working example of how to upload a file using Delphi CGI.

I have googled but so far haven't had any luck.

This is what I have been trying but I am getting access violations.

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1WebActionItem1Action(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  lFileName   : string;
  lFileStream : TFileStream;
begin
  lFileName   := Request.Files[0].FileName;
  lFileStream := TFileStream.Create(lFileName, fmCreate);
  try
    lFileStream.CopyFrom(Request.Files[0].Stream, Request.Files[0].Stream.Size);
  finally
    lFileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Where does the access violation come from? Is Request valid? How many files does it have in the Files array? Is the first file's Stream property valid? What is its size? Is the file name valid for your file system?